# SharePoint upgrade process

Tags: powershell, upgrade

What is the meaning of the phrase "build to build" upgrade in the context of cmdlets `Mount-SPContentDatabase` and `Upgrade-SPContentDatabase`?

Answer (score 1):

Their are two terms used, Build to Build & Version-to Version upgrade.

**Build-to-Build**  You can upgrade to a minor release, such as an update or patch, or to a major release.Another words, when you apply CU/Hot fix/SP/Public Updates etc then you run the upgrade which will perform Build-to-Build upgrade. An upgrade to a minor release is called a build-to-build upgrade.

> After you finish the patch phase, you must complete the update
>   installation by starting the build-to-build upgrade phase. The
>   build-to-build upgrade phase is task intensive and, therefore, takes
>   the most time to finish. The first action is to upgrade all the
>   SharePoint processes that are running. After you upgrade the
>   processes, the databases are crawled and upgraded. After you complete
>   a farm upgrade on one server, you have to complete the process on all
>   other servers to maintain incompatibility.

**Version-to-Version**An upgrade to a major release is called a version-to-version upgrade.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff806329.aspx